# After changing multiple buttons highlight color, buttons disappears on click

Tags: c#, button, unity-game-engine, highlight

I want to give my players the option of changing some of the menu colors including the button highlights. Even though it took me quite some head scratching I made a function that changes the highlights of all buttons in my list, but there's a weird side effect, now buttons disappear on click and then briefly show the highlight while re-appearing back to normal state.

I don't understand what's going on at all and there's no errors.

All buttons have the default Color Tint Transition And here's my code:

```
public List<Color> Colors = new List<Color>();
public List<Button> Buttons = new List<Button>();

public void ButtonHighlights(int colorSelected)
{
    foreach (var button in Buttons)
    {
        Button btn = button.GetComponent<Button>(); 
        ColorBlock cb = btn.colors;
        cb.highlightedColor = Colors[colorSelected];
        btn.colors = cb;
    }
}
```

If anyone has any ideas, please share them! Thanks in advance.

Comment: Side question: why are you using the count variable in a while loop instead of just using a foreach loop? You are over-complicating everything

Comment: It's been a while since i've coded and i'm just trying to get it to work first and i'll re-write/improve it later when i'm back into it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really silly now but the problem wasn't script related, i set the A value of the colors in "Colors" list, in the editor to 0 instead of 255 for some reason.

Answer (score 0):

I will redo this but, question do you have the highlighted color switched to null on any buttons. If so that is your problem. You are basically changing every buttons highlighted color to null.

Comment: I don't but perhaps it could be because of the ColorBlock, don't have much experience using this, maybe i should change the pressed colors aswell